# Splinter object has no attribute click

Tags: python, attributeerror, splinter

I'm trying to download a file from the Department of Education and this is my complete code as it stands so far:

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

br = Browser()
br.visit('http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/cipcode/resources.aspx?y=55')
br.find_by_xpath('//*[id@"ct100_ct100_CIPContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton_FINALCIPtoSOCcrosswalk"]').click()

# give myself a delay to visually inspect that it's working
time.sleep(5)
br.quit()
```

And this is the complete traceback that I get

```
File "crosswalksplinter.py", line 9, in <module>
 br.find_by_xpath('//*[id@"ct100_ct100_CIPContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton_FINALCIPtoSOCcrosswalk"]').click()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 75, in __getattr__
 self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I've "clicked" on other links like this before so I'm not sure what the problem is this time.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and if there is a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message it looks like the stuff returned from `br.find_by_xpath` is a list, not a single element. The [`splinter docs`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/finding.html#finding-elements) confirm this:

> Splinter provides 6 methods for finding elements in the page, one for each selector type: css, xpath, tag, name, id, value. ... Each of these methods returns a list with the found elements.

It also says:

> You can get the first found element with the first shortcut:
>   `first_found = browser.find_by_name('name').first`

Try clicking the first element like this:

```
br.find_by_xpath('//*[id@"ct100_ct100_CIPContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton_FINALCIPtoSOCcrosswalk"]').first.click()
```

Or using the list index:

```
br.find_by_xpath('//*[id@"ct100_ct100_CIPContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton_FINALCIPtoSOCcrosswalk"]')[0].click()
```

Comment: @Jon Then the element you are looking for wasn't found. You may have your xpath wrong. See [`ElementDoesNotExist` exception](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/finding.html#elementdoesnotexist-exception).

Comment: Yeah I guess I had a typo in my xpath, I recopied and pasted and added the .first and it works now, thank you!

Comment: (at least in newer /2018/ versions of splinter) this should be proxied (see readthedocs) from ElementList to its first object. The calls ElementList.click() ; ElementList.first.click() ; ElementList[0].click() should be identical.